# Can we get wrist raised event for apple watch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch

We have started with apple watch and gone through many documents and links.

We want to build some use cases when user raises his/her wrist when using apple watch.

Even if going through many documents and links still below question is uncleared.

Is it possible to get any event in objective c when user raises his/her wrist?

Please advise if my question is not clear here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, with current API it's not possible.
However Watch/WatchKit somehow can distinguish this gesture, short-look/long-look notification mechanism is based on that.